# update specified property without re-passing the whole object mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
module.exports.updateProduct = function(product_id,product,callback){
    var update = {
        name: product.name,
        image: product.image,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        discount_price: product.d_price,
        category_id: product.category_id,
        user_id: product.user_id
    }

    Products.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":product_id}, update ,{upsert: true,'new':true}, callback);
}
```

I saw this code and I know what it does. It basically update the document. But it's possible if I want to update for example just `price` without passing the entire `update` object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, use the `$set` operator:

```
Products.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": product_id}, {$set: {price: product.price}}, opts);
```

Comment: what is the last param for? opts? is that optional?

Comment: @JamieJordan yes it is optional. It is used for specifying options for the given command.

Comment: it doesn't work. It has no error, I pass in the correct id and price, doesn't reflect the changes in my db. It still shows the old data.

Comment: the opts is not optional, I remove it the query does nothing, but when i put {new:true} it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by using `$set` like:

```
Products.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":product_id}, {$set: {price: product.price}}, {new: true}, function (error, updateProduct) {
        // where {new: true} is option that is optional 
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, null); // if error return error and null as data in callback params
        }
        return callback(false, updateProduct); // return update product for success and false for error flag
    });
```

Comment: what does new `here` means?

Comment: `{new: true}` means you will get updated information by default you will get original doc instead of updated doc.

Comment: uh can you explain it again? I'm confused with ur sentence.

Comment: ok, if you use `{new: true}` option then you will get updated document (means with updated price) otherwise will get previous document.

Comment: [Callbacks should be *error-first*](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/). Also you’re ignoring the error here. Just replace your whole callback with `callback` : `Products.findOneAndUpdate(…, callback);`